# downloading files via javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am trying to download some csv content via button click.

On click i have a javascript function that downloads the file using

```
window.location='data:application/webcsv;charset=utf8,' + encodeURIComponent(csvData);
```

But this file does not have any name and extension. How can i assign a file name using javascript?

Comment: See here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3665115/create-a-file-in-memory-for-user-to-download-not-through-server

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't specify filename or extension via the [data uri](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Data_URI_scheme). But if you use an `<a>` element, you can use the [`[download]` attribute](http://www.w3.org/html/wg/drafts/html/master/single-page.html#downloading-resources):

```
<a href="data:..set dynamically.." download="filename.extension">Download</a>
```

It's not supported in every browser, but it's a start.

Comment: thanks. this worked out for me. inside the function i changed the href of an anchor tag which onclick downloaded the file with proper extension.

Comment: can u suggest a solution for mobile browsers too.

Comment: @sharmacal, if I knew one, I'd suggest it. Unfortunately, `[download]` is a little too new to be widely supported. I use it on a custom template builder for myself, but that's because I know I'm going to use chrome.

Answer (score 0):

There's no way to download a file with a specified filename using pure JS that I know of - a combination of JS and Flash can be used though.

Check out the [Downloadify](http://davidwalsh.name/downloadify) library - I used it to do just this same thing recently...